# How can I request pipeline processors in Apache Wicket?

Tags: apache, wicket

Is there any way to request pipeline processors in Apache Wicket? Possibly with an open-source framework that integrates with Wicket?

I want to check requests before my web pages are rendered.

Answer (score 1):

In Wicket 1.4.x, you have to extend `[Web]RequestCycle`, so that you an override the hook methods (`onBeginRequest()`, `onEndRequest()`, `onAfterTargetsDetached()`, etc.), and override `Application.newRequestCycle()` to return the custom class.

In Wicket 1.5.x, this mechanism has been refactored, so you can just implement the `RequestCycleListener`, which provides the same hooks. This new mechanism is much better, since you can compose and reuse listeners.

Answer (score 0):

In Wicket 1.4.x (don't know if this has been kept in 1.5) you have  `RequestCycle#onBeginRequest()` and `RequestCycle#onEndRequest()` that you can override.